# Appending values to trigger.new

Tags: trigger

I am facing a problem.

I want to insert or rather say update a value in trigger.New, I am using it in before insert.

This is the trigger.New:

```
Uporabnik__c:{Id=null, IsDeleted=false, Name=test, Bonus__c=null}
```

I want to insert a number in the Bonus__c field, so it would look like:

```
Uporabnik__c:{Id=null, IsDeleted=false, Name=test, Bonus__c=1200}
```

I have tried several methods but none worked. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Strongly suggest you work your way through [Get Started with Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro).

Comment: Is there a reason to use a trigger instead of a record triggered flow for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this based on your requirement.

```
 for(Uporabnik__c obj: Trigger.new) {
        obj.Bonus__c = 1200;
    }
```